# CSS 3 scrollbar - add padding and cursor?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How can I add these two things on the scrollbar?

1. padding around the scrollbar
2. a cursor when you hover the scrollbar

This is my code:

```
    #style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-track
    {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    #style-4::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
        width: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;

    }

    #style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    {
        background-color: #ccc;

    }

    #style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
    {
        background-color: #666;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

You can see it [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/dqpy5hyr). I want to add the padding like the ones on cssdeck.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About that padding. Sample 5px padding from left

```
#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px; /* add 5px */
    ...
}

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 white; /* change color to your bg color */
    ...
}
```

Adding `cursor: pointer` to every `-webkit-scrollbar` element does not unfortunately work.

Answer (score -3):

Yes You can add it.

```
    #style-4:hover{
  padding:15px;
}
```

I think this is correct, if im wrong please let know what you expect.

Answer (score -3):

Try this one for Cursor

```
#style-4:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```