# How do I customize the cursor for scrollbar-hover in css?

Tags: css, scrollbar, mouse-cursor

I'm using tumblr. And I use the following code to change the cursor for the **main body** and **hover on links**:

```
body, a { cursor:url("http://i.imgur.com/2qleX.jpg"), auto}
a:hover { cursor:url("http://i.imgur.com/IepP2.jpg"), auto}
```

But it doesn't seem to affect the **scrollbar** I have added to one of the containers, which is:

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

The cursor simply changes back to the default browser cursor when I hover/click the scrollbar. How do I customize the cursor for the scrollbar???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change cursor image on scrollbar in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764646/change-cursor-image-on-scrollbar-in-chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS 3 scrollbar - add padding and cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799493/css-3-scrollbar-add-padding-and-cursor)

Comment: you can customise many aspects of the scrollbars with `::-webkit-scrollbar` and it's related family of pseudo-elements. Unfortunately, `cursor` is not one of the properties you can change there.

Comment: Those Q&A referrals don't help me :/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{cursor:url("http://i.imgur.com/2qleX.jpg"), auto}
```

More on how to customize scrollbars: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp